# Golang: Implement Interface with method that accepts argument of union type

Tags: go

I have an interface that defines a method `Calculate`. This method can have two different implementations and it will accept slightly different argument for each implementation. After reading about Generics in Go I am thinking about using Union type here like this:

```
type MinimumInfo struct {
    name string
}
type ExtendedInfo struct {
    name        string
    description string
}

// Define new type as Union of both structures
type Info interface {
    MinimumInfo | ExtendedInfo
}

// Interface with the method that accepts Generic parameter
type Calculator[T Info] interface {
    Calculate(info *T)
}
```

Then I have two different implementations of this method. The first implementation works with `MinimumInfo`, so I have following code for it:

```
// Implement Calculator method for MinimumInfo
type BasicCalculator[T MinimumInfo] struct {
}

func (b *BasicCalculator[T]) Calculate(info *T) {
    fmt.Println("From basic calculator")
    fmt.Printf("Object %+v \n", info)

    // This does not work
    //fmt.Printf("Name is %s \n", info.name)
}
```

And the second implementation requires `ExtendedInfo` and looks like this:

```
// Implement Calculator method for ExtendedInfo
type ExtendedCalculator[T ExtendedInfo] struct {
}

func (b *ExtendedCalculator[T]) Calculate(info *T) {
    fmt.Println("From extended calculator")
    fmt.Printf("Object %+v \n", info)

    // This does not work
    //fmt.Printf("Name is %s \n", info.name)
}
```

`main` has following code:

```
func main() {
    info1 := &MinimumInfo{
        name: "minimum",
    }
    calc := &BasicCalculator[MinimumInfo]{}
    calc.Calculate(info1)

    info2 := &ExtendedInfo{
        name:        "extended",
        description: "description",
    }
    calc2 := &ExtendedCalculator[ExtendedInfo]{}
    calc2.Calculate(info2)
}
```

It's also available in Go playground - https://go.dev/play/p/BVgR3iA4VAn

The problem is that with this approach I cannot access object fields (e.g. `info.name`) in `Calculate` method even though it prints out correct object. I commented out line that does not work.

I am not sure if I understood properly how generics should work in Go, but at this point it's not clear where the problem is and why it cannot recognize object type.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here?